# IF function not returning the correct value when it references a zero

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using IF statements that work well when there are dates in the cells. My cell G8 calcs the number of months correctly. However, when the calulated number of months is zero it should return a zero value but it still calculates the number of maximum months.

In initial cell G8 I'm using the formula:

```
=IF(C8="","0",DATEDIF(C8,E8,"m"))
```

This correctly returns zero months when cell C8 is blank.

In the next cell H8, I'm using

```
=IF(G8>=25,"25",G8)
```

to max out the number of months at 25. It works well except when cell G8 is zero it is still return the maximum value of 25. I thought it would return 0.

I'm stumped. Any thoughts? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your true condition in your `if` is passing `0` as a string, not a number. Take it out of the quotation marks. Same with 25.

Answer (score 0):

Your zero is `"0"`, which is TEXT, NOT A NUMBER.

Therefore you shouldn't compare it to a number.

Exclude `"`s around `0` in your first formula.

Comment: @user531704 if your problem is solved, please click the green checkmark next to the answer to mark the question as answered